# Looking for a couple of sequence satisfying some conditions

Tags: sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Find $(c_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $(e_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ s.t.

0. $e_n>0$ for all n;
1. $c_n$ decreases to zero as n goes to infinity;
2. $c_{n+1}^{-e_n}>K$ for all n, where K is a constant strictly bigger than 1;
3. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_{n+1}^{-e_n}log(c_{n+1}^{-1})[c_n^{e_n}-c_{n+1}^{e_n}] < \infty$

I have seen that $c_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and $e_n=\frac{1}{n}$ satisfy point 1 and 3, while $c_{n+1}^{-e_n}$ goes to 1 as n goes to infinity.
I have not been able to start from my example and obtain a different couple of sequences satisfying point 2 too.

Any idea?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Concerning the second condition, note that $c_{n+1}^{-e_n} \ge K > 1$ $\forall n \ge 1$ doesn't forbid $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} c_{n+1}^{-e_n} = 1$, so that your example is valid.

Comment: It is also to be noted that the first condition is ambiguous : do you want $c_n$ to be a decreasing sequence or is it only constrained by $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} c_n = 0$ ?

Comment: Finally, the last condition is ambiguous too. Do you allow series diverging towards $-\infty$ ?

Comment: @Abezhiko thank you for your replies. The first condition says that the sequence goes to 0 decreasing, so it is clearly a decreasing sequence. About the third one: the sequence in the sum has positive values definitively (actually, they are all positive if $c_1<1$). At last, i think your comment about the second condition is wrong.